# How to only overwrite @material theme color for one component?

Tags: css, sass, material-components, material-components-web

The `$mdc-theme-secondary: #6b2574` is already defined on top of the index.scss file.

I have a material checkbox component that by default uses the `$mdc-theme-secondary` as the background color. I want to change the color of the checkbox without modifying `mdc-theme-secondary`.

I was looking at [the material documentation](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-checkbox) 
.

```
mdc-checkbox-container-colors($unmarked-stroke-color, $unmarked-fill-color, $marked-stroke-color, $marked-fill-color, $generate-keyframes)
```

It provides this mixin, but after trying different things, I still have no idea how to use it. I couldn't find any examples either.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Did you try adding your own class with higher specifity?

Comment: yeah. I have tried something like: .checkbox-background{ background-color: red}. I could overwrite it in chrome. But it always got overwritten by #mdc-theme-secondary@AdamOrlov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@import "@material/checkbox/mdc-checkbox";
.mdc-checkbox {
  @include mdc-checkbox-container-colors($mdc-theme-secondary, $mdc-theme-on-secondary, 
  $mdc-theme-primary, $mdc-theme-on-primary);
}
```

I figured out how to use the mixin... I have to select .mdc-checkbox.